# problem populate spinner android kotlin with room database

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to populate spinner with room database in kotlin but items in spinner are different. the number of items are true. exactly I want to make ArrayList of title in **Category Class** and show them in spinner in a fragment

```
@Entity(tableName = "cat_table")

class Category(val title: String,
               val fulType: Int,
               val SaleP: Long,
               val BuyP: Long,
               var created: Date = Date()
            ) {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}`
```

by this an want to show all title in ArrayList and set to spinner

```
private fun initData() {
        val packageTypesAdapter = context?.let {ArrayAdapter<Any>(it,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)}
        catViewModel!!.allCats.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { packageTypes ->
            packageTypes?.forEach {packageTypesAdapter!!.add(it)}
        })
        spinner2.adapter = packageTypesAdapter

        spinner2.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>, view: View, i: Int, l: Long) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "$packageTypesAdapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                //if (i == 0) {
                //    loadAllTodos()
                //} else {
                //   val string: String = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                //   loadFilteredTodos(string)
                //}
            }
            override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>) {
            }
        }
}`
```

if use this query

```
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM cat_table WHERE title ")
 val allCatTitle: LiveData<List<Category>>
```

spinner nothing to show and below query are like this picture

```
@get:Query("SELECT * FROM cat_table ORDER BY created DESC")
val allCatByDate: LiveData<List<Category>>
```

[Please check the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvKGH.jpg)

Comment: There was no one

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else bumps into the same issue. Here's how I did it a while ago (Kotlin).

**Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT deviceName FROM device_table WHERE deviceType = :deviceType")
fun getDevice(deviceType: String): LiveData<List<String>>
```

**Repository**

```
fun getDevice(deviceType: String): LiveData<List<String>> {
    return deviceDao.getDevice(deviceType)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
fun getDevice(deviceType: String): LiveData<List<String>> {
  return repository.getDevice(deviceType)
}
```

And finally in my fragment:

```
private fun initSpinnerData() {
    val spinner3 = view?.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinnerRecord_devices)

    if (spinner3 != null) {
        val allDevices = context?.let {
            ArrayAdapter<Any>(it, R.layout.spinner_text)
        }
        mDevicesViewModel.getDevice("Appliance")
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { devices ->
                devices?.forEach {
                    allDevices?.add(it)
                }
            })
        spinner3.adapter = allDevices

        spinner3.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$allDevices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }
    }
}
```